# Django - Cannot combine a unique query with a non-unique query or pub_date field look up not available

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Trying to filter queries by name & datetime. The query should fulfill both criteria, i tried using field lookup in single query using pub_date__date field lookup , it threw the error pub_date not available, then i tried using date field, but that didnt work either. dtt here is = datetime.datetime.now()

```
orders = OrderItemss.objects.filter(customer=customer_object, pub_date__date= str(dtt.day))

orders = OrderItemss.objects.filter(customer=customer_object, date= str(dtt.date())
```

when i tried combining 2 queries using & , it throws the error 'Cannot combine a unique query with a non-unique query'                  code:

```
orders = OrderItemss.objects.filter(customer=customer_object) & Customer.objects.datetimes('date', 'hour', order='DESC')
```

Here is the models object, I'm using Psql:

```
class OrderItemss(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (f'{self.quantity} of {self.item.name}')

    def get_total_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.old_price

    def get_final_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.price

    def get_amount_saved(self):
        return self.get_final_price - self.get_total_item_price
```

Comment: please share your model.

Comment: Your `OrderItemss` has no `pub_date` field, only a `date` field (which is not a `DateField`, but a `DateTimeField`).

Comment: how to query using date and time from datetime field?

Comment: Also in the official docs it says that pub_date works with datetime fields. Also filtering by timestamp is not working.

Comment: Have you tried `date__date=datetime.date.today()`, without the "pub_" prefix? The docs just use "pub_date" as an example

Comment: @samar2170: no, this works with a model that *has* a `pub_date` field. All filtering of course works in the *context* of a model.

Comment: I cant find any docs on pub_date field ? how to use the pub_date field. I'm using Django 3.0.6.

Comment: @samar2170 "pub_date" is just an example field name used in the docs, it is nothing more. Your field is named "date" so just replace all instances of "pub_date" in the examples with "date"

Comment: @samar2170: I think you simply are interpreting the documentation too strict. The entire idea is that if they show something like `Book.objects.filter(pub_date=...)`, then they likely already explained somewhere that they *defined* a `Book` model with a `pub_date` field, `pub_date` is thus a field of that specific model. It is thus an example how to query, but if your model has fields with a different name, then of course you can not use `pub_date`.

Comment: Thanks @IainShelvington You are  lifesavers, can't belive it was such a silly error.